# Does primer lose its bond surface after a period of time?

Tags: painting

I read somewhere that you should paint a few days after applying primer or the primer may lose its ability to bond with the paint.

Is this true and what happens if you have to wait for a week after applying the primer before you can  paint ?

Comment: That's really a product-specific question. There's no general answer. I've never heard of that situation, though.

Comment: "*Is this true*"  ***No*, i do not think that is true**. In a related question:  Does your chewing gum loose its flavor on the best post over night ?

Comment: In some industrial paint systems that is true . But I doubt it is true for any domestic paint; just follow the instructions.for top-coat.

Comment: I believe the problem would be more of contamination, dust or other airborne debris like oil residue from a busy road or cooking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but in real world sense, no.   Yes it does lose its binding principles due to other molecules/materials interfering with its surface or its surface decaying (at a super super low rate).

Your main enemy is grease, dirt, and dust.   You will have to clean the walls well (use soapy bucket and scruffy sponge, let it dry after cleaning then Windex and paper towels after).   As far as chemically breaking down it does but at a slow rate.  You can tell when it does because it gets shiny and flat looking - takes years.

The other part of it is that newer paints that are quality are paint/primer combos.   You are good if you clean it well after it sits a year.